# Android, Is it possible to run the app in background?

Tags: android

I am designing an application which has the following requirements :

1. Add multiple addresses and show the route of address on map.
2. When user clicks on begin route button, googles "turn-by-turn" app is opened and my app goes into background.
3. When user reaches to particular address,my app again comes in foreground and shows one pop-up message, then start the other route in googles "turn-by-turn app", I used broadcast receiver to bring my app into foreground.

My question is, when my app goes in background and "turn-by-turn" app starts, after user reaches to particular address sometimes it will not return to my app, and when I intentionally open my app it will not be in running mode.

Edited Question :

I have created the service where the proximity alert is started for notifying about the location :

```
public class LocationUpdateBoundService extends Service implements LocationListener{
private static final long POINT_RADIUS = 200; // in Meters
private static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1;
private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.routerapp.ProximityAlert";
private final BroadcastReceiver tProximityAlrt = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
PendingIntent proximityIntent;

private static int requestCode = 1;
private LocationManager locationManager; 
public Location location;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try{

        int LAST_COUNT= intent.getIntExtra("LAST_COUNT",90);
         double LATITUDE=intent.getDoubleExtra("LATITUDE",0);
         double LONGITUDE=intent.getDoubleExtra("LONGITUDE",0);
         String ROUTE_NAME=intent.getStringExtra("ROUTE_NAME");
         String ROUTE_ADDRESS=intent.getStringExtra("ROUTE_ADDRESS");
         String ROUTE_NOTE=intent.getStringExtra("ROUTE_NOTE");
         int ROUTE_ID=intent.getIntExtra("ROUTE_ID",90);
         int ROUTE_TOTAL=intent.getIntExtra("ROUTE_TOTAL",90);
         boolean STOP_WATCH=intent.getBooleanExtra("STOP_WATCH",false);

     Toast.makeText(this, "Service ROUTE_NAME="+LATITUDE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location From GPS
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                // Log.d(TAG, "route_size 1= " + location.getLatitude());
                // onLocationChanged(location);
                if (location != null) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, "route_size2= " + route_size);
                    onLocationChanged(location);

                }
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "SERVICE START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     addProximityAlert(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,ROUTE_ADDRESS,ROUTE_NOTE,ROUTE_ID,STOP_WATCH,ROUTE_NAME,ROUTE_TOTAL);
    }catch(NullPointerException e)
    {

    }



    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

}

private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude,
         String ROUTE_ADDRESS, String ROUTE_NOTE, int ROUTE_ID, boolean stop_watch_activated,String route_name,int total_route) {

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("location_title", route_name);
    extras.putString("location", ROUTE_ADDRESS);
    extras.putString("note", ROUTE_NOTE);
    extras.putInt("unique_id", ROUTE_ID);
    extras.putInt("total_route", total_route);
    extras.putBoolean("stop_watch", stop_watch_activated);

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(PROX_ALERT_INTENT, extras);
     proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            LocationUpdateBoundService.this, requestCode, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, // the latitude of the
                                                // central point of the
                                                // alert region
            longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert
                        // region
            POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert
                            // region, in meters
            PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in
                                    // milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no
                                    // expiration
            proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire
                            // when entry to or exit from the alert region
                            // is detected
            );
    requestCode++;

    initialiseAlertReceiver() ;

}


private void initialiseAlertReceiver() {
    // PROXI ALERT FOR NOTE
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(tProximityAlrt, filter);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Toast.makeText(LocationUpdateBoundService.this, "SERVICE DISTROYED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// DEACTIVATE PROXIMITYALER
locationManager.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent);
unregisterReceiver(tProximityAlrt);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String location_title;
String location;
String note;
int total_route;
private static int unique_id = 0;

boolean is_alertAvailable=false;
boolean stop_watch;
//private SettingSharedPreference pref;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    is_alertAvailable=false;


    Bundle bndlBundle=intent.getBundleExtra("com.routerapp.ProximityAlert");

    unique_id = bndlBundle.getInt("unique_id");


    total_route= bndlBundle.getInt("total_route");
    location = bndlBundle.getString("location");
    location_title = bndlBundle.getString("location_title");
    note = bndlBundle.getString(
            "note");
    stop_watch=bndlBundle.getBoolean("stop_watch");

    Toast.makeText(context, "BroadcastReceiver START="+location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(!stop_watch)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "LAST POINT REACHED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DrivingRouteActivity.is_last_point=true;
    }


    for(Integer uniqueID:DrivingRouteActivity.tArrayOfBroaCastReceiver)
    {
        if(uniqueID==unique_id)
        {
            is_alertAvailable=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //OPEN THE APPLICATION MAP ACTIVITY
    if(!is_alertAvailable)
    {
        DrivingRouteActivity.tArrayOfBroaCastReceiver.add(unique_id);
        Intent i = new Intent(context,
                NotificationView.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("location", location);
        i.putExtra("location_title", location_title);
        i.putExtra("note", note);
        i.putExtra("total_route", total_route);
        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

    }

}

}
```

And In the activity which is started by the broadcast receiver

```
public class NotificationView extends Activity {
SettingSharedPreference pref;
private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.routerapp.ProximityAlert";
// Typeface type;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_location_leached_dialog);

    Button tBackbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_4_alert_back);
    TextView tTextNote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_4_alert_note);
    TextView tTextTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_4_alert_title);
    TextView tTextSubTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_4_alert_subtitle);
    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

    tTextNote.setText(data.getString("note"));
    tTextTitle.setText(data.getString("location_title"));
    tTextSubTitle.setText(data.getString(""));
    DrivingRouteActivity.is_route_end_automatically = true;
    pref = new SettingSharedPreference(this);;
    if(DrivingRouteActivity.is_last_point)
    {
        tBackbutton.setText(R.string.btn_end_route);
    }


    if (pref.getNotePopup()) {

    } else {

        finish();

    }
    tBackbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();

        }
    });


    //KILL THE SERVICE
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,
             LocationUpdateBoundService.class);
             stopService(intent);


}

}
```

Also the state of app is stored to maintain the app state when it is destroyed.

But when the system stops running my app in background, I will not able to receive the broadcast.

Not getting what is the problem.

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: If you open navigation app for result, it will come back to your app after user completes that activity. I think the broadcast receiver is not needed. You can simply get the data from result and instantiate your activity according to that data.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping you with problems you face while programming, not giving you full code solutions.
What have you tried so far? Where did you face a problem? Please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Android like java has garbage collection, and android will close down apps if to much memory is being used elsewhere. So it is possible that during the time the Google Maps is up guiding your user that Android OS shuts down your applications and removes it from memory to free up space for something else.

However without any code I cant realy give you any more information or advice. Other than in the broadcast receiver start and Intent to open up your application and make sure that the state of your app is stored when the app is destroyed so that you can bring it up where you left off before.